# Создание Android сервиса

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarm-manager

Здравствуйте. Начал осваивание программирования под Android. Первая задача довольно простая и в общем смысле следующая: фоновый сервис с определённым промежутком времени, который настраивается в основном приложении (5/10/20... мин), делает запрос на сервер, получает с него некие данные и выводит уведомление. При этом если само уведомление ещё висит, то запрос на сервер не делается, а отсрочивается на тот момент, когда уведомление будет удалено + настроенный промежуток.

Пока с задачей справился таким образом: висит сервис, который при своём старте запускает таймер с интервалом, к примеру, в 60 секунд, который проверяет несколько вещей: для начала смотрит попадает ли текущее время в настроенное рабочее время, дабы в ночное время не приходили уведомления, далее прошло ли уже достаточное количество времени с показа последнего уведомления и не отображается ли сейчас предыдущее уведомление.

И вроде бы всё работает, но когда телефон долго не трогаешь, он переходит в некий свой режим сна и таймер может не срабатывать и по несколько десятков минут, и если сделать интервал таймера чаще, скажем секунд в 20-30, то идёт очень быстрый расход батареи моим приложением.

В связи с этим решил спросить умных опытных людей, как в Android это правильно обычно реализуется? В какую сторону копать?

Нашёл такую вещь, как AlarmManager, как я понял, именно он и позволяет спать сервису, то есть не занимать процессорное время и расходовать батарею, пока его не "вызовут", при этом "вызов" происходит по-любому, даже в "сонном" состоянии или не спать, а просто запускать сервис по расписанию, что так же подходит. Поправьте, если не прав. Поможет ли он в моём случае или может есть что-то другое?

Если это имеет значение, то тестирую на Samsung Note 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имеет значение не модель телефона, а версия Android. Думаю, что у вас как минимум 6.0.

Значит пора изучить новшество, появившееся в Android 6.0, `Doze Mode`.
Как раз оно и усложняет жизнь вашему приложению.
Чтобы понять `Doze Mode`, изучите официальный тренинг:
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

И как вы верно написали, `AlarmManager` поможет вам, но обратите внимание на методы, которые предназначены для `Doze Mode`.
И обязательно еще раз продумайте саму идею приложения, действительно ли необходимо всегда выходить из `Doze Mode` и как часто действительно необходимо это делать.

> Note: Neither setAndAllowWhileIdle() nor setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() can fire alarms more than once per 9 minutes, per app.

Comment: Благодарю, с этим ознакомился, написал, потестил (Android 7). В связи с эти что хотел бы ещё узнать:

в Doze Mode, который включаю через Adb, сервис срабатывает примерно раз в 10 минут, при этом не имея подключения к интернету. Хотя использую функции setExactAndAllowWhileIdle или setAndAllowWhileIdle (не совсем понял разницу между ними) с интервалом в 30 секунд и флагом RTC_WAKEUP.

Каждый раз подключение к инету мне не нужно, но иногда нужно. Как можно решить этот вопрос?

Comment: Ситуацию может поменять включённое разрешение IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, но я так понимаю, что это очень плохое решение.

Как вообще решают этот вопрос различные мессенджеры? Когда мне отправляют сообщение, они достаточно быстро реагируют.

Я ещё наткнулся на такую вещь, как Firebase Job Dispatcher, уместна ли она в моей текущей задаче?

Comment: Мессенджеры используют пуш-нотификации. Т.е. по сути спят пока сервер сам их не разбудит. У вас совсем другой случай.

Comment: Разница между `setXXX` и `setExactXXX`, что для первого система может передвигать время срабатывания на свое усмотрение, т.е. не гарантируется абсолютно точное время срабатывания.

Comment: По первому комменту, добавил цитату из документации. За 30 секунд никто и заснуть не успеет :)

Comment: Получается в таких случаях, как мой как раз и используют AlarmManager с включённым IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS ?

Comment: Если пользователь будет готов пожертвовать временем жизни на батарее ради функционала вашего приложения, то да.

Comment: Я вас понял. В данном случае приложение как бы учебное и делаю лично для себя, так что тут лично мне решать. А так запомню, что это не есть хорошо и злоупотреблять не стоит. Благодарю за консультацию.